# dict' object has no attribute 'key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

```
 def vulscan (scan_ip):
     nm = nmap.PortScanner()
     print('start')
     res = nm.scan(hosts=scan_ip, arguments="-sV --script=vulscan/vulscan.nse")
     ports = res['scan'][scan_ip]['tcp'] 
     print(ports)
     ports = ports.key()
     ports = list(ports)

     product = []
     for i in ports:
         product = produnct + res['scan'][scan_ip][int(i)]['product']
     print(product)
     print('done')
```

res and ports are  dicts and i want to get the key of the ports so i used key(). And i don't why i just get this :dict' object has no attribute 'key'

I try to copy the ports into anthoer dict named temp  out of this function like this

```
 country = {443: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'http', 'product': 'Siemens Simatic S7-1200 PLC httpd', 'version': '', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '10', 'cpe': '', 'script': {'vulscan': "VulDB - https://vuldb.com:\n[171297] Siemens SIMATIC S7-PLCSIM 5.4 divide by zero\n[171296] Siemens SIMATIC S7-PLCSIM 5.4 null pointer dereference\n[171295] Siemens SIMATIC S7-PLCSIM 5.4 infinite loop\n[64009] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC 2.0 memory corruption\n[64008] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC 2.0 memory corruption\n[62667] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC up to 2.0 cross site scripting\n[62420] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 Plc 2.0 weak encryption\n[176574] Siemens SIMATIC RF166C Request denial of service\n[176062] Siemens SIMATIC Drive Controller Service Port 102 memory corruption\n[174983] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels up to 16 Update 3 Device Layout memory corruption\n[174982] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels up to 16 Update 3 SmartVNC memory corruption\n[174981] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels up to 16 Update 3 exceptional condition\n[174980] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels up to 16 Update 3 out-of-bounds write\n[174979] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels up to 16 Update 3 out-of-bounds write\n[174975] Siemens SIMATIC NET CP 343-1 Service Port 102 resource consumption\n[174971] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels up to 16 Update 3 Device Layout out-of-bounds write\n[174968] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panels SNMP Service out-of-bounds write\n[174966] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Outdoor Panels SmartVNC Device Layout resource consumption\n[171269] Siemens SIMATIC MV400 up to 7.0.5 TCP Stack denial of service\n[171053] Siemens SIMATIC MV400 up to 7.0.5 ISN Generator initialization\n[169560] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel up to 16 Update 2 Telnet Service missing authentication\n[169557] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7/SIMATIC WinCC authentication bypass\n[161082] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 CPU/SIMATIC S7-400 CPU Password information disclosure\n[161078] Siemens SIMATIC HMI United Comfort Panel weak authentication\n[161077] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Basic Panel Brute Force information disclosure\n[158070] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Basic Panel weak encryption\n[158067] Siemens SIMATIC S7-200 SMART CPU up to 2.5.0 denial of service\n[151215] Siemens OpenPCS 7/SIMATIC memory corruption\n[151214] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 denial of service\n[151211] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 CPU/SINUMERIK 840D sl denial of service\n[149975] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CPU up to V4.1) Web Server denial of service\n[143330] Siemens SIMATIC IT UADM up to 1.2 Service Port 1434 Credentials information disclosure\n[143328] Siemens SIMATIC/SINAMICS denial of service\n[143327] Siemens SIMATIC/SINAMICS IRT denial of service\n[141765] Siemens SIMATIC TDC CP51M1 up to 1.1.6 UDP Packet privilege escalation\n[139983] Siemens SIMATIC ET 200SP Open Controller CPU 1515SP PC Service Port 102 privilege escalation\n[139981] Siemens SIMATIC ET 200SP Open Controller CPU 1515SP PC Service Port 102 privilege escalation\n[137760] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7/SIMATIC WinCC File Upload privilege escalation\n[136421] Siemens SIMATIC Ident MV420/SIMATIC Ident MV440 weak encryption\n[136420] Siemens SIMATIC Ident MV420/SIMATIC Ident MV440 privilege escalation\n[135050] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel Web Server cross site scripting\n[135049] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel TLS Session Key weak encryption\n[135047] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel SNMP privilege escalation\n[135031] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7/SIMATIC WinCC privilege escalation\n[135027] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7/SIMATIC WinCC DCOM Interface privilege escalation\n[135025] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7/SIMATIC WinCC Project File privilege escalation\n[133453] Siemens SIMATIC CP443-1 OPC UA OPC Service privilege escalation\n[133438] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 CPU S7 Packet denial of service\n[133437] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CPU 2.0/2.1/2.2/2.3/2.4 privilege escalation\n[133436] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CPU 2.0/2.1/2.2/2.3/2.4 privilege escalation\n[127945] Siemens SIMATIC S7-410 Service Port 102 privilege escalation\n[127944] Siemens SIMATIC S7-410 Service Port 102 privilege escalation\n[127937] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 up to 2.5 Connection denial of service\n[127936] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel Webserver Header Injection privilege escalation\n[127935] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel Webserver Redirect\n[127934] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel Security Vulnerability TP/MP/OP/MP directory traversal\n[127932] Siemens SIMATIC IT LMS weak authentication\n[125230] Siemens SIMATIC ET/SIMATIC S7-1500/SIMATIC S7-1500 Network Stack denial of service\n[125227] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 up to 4.2.2 Web Interface cross site request forgery\n[123945] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC up to 3.14 Service Port TCP 5678 privilege escalation\n[117823] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400/SIMATIC S7-400H Data Processing Error\n[117078] Siemens OpenPCS/SIMATIC BATCH/SIMATIC NET PC-Software RPC Service privilege escalation\n[114820] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC CONTROL Script privilege escalation\n[114819] Siemens SIMATIC PROFINET DCP Request privilege escalation\n[111023] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Data Processing Error\n[109157] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7 up to 8.1 DCOM Interface privilege escalation\n[105984] Siemens SIMATIC Wincc Runtime up to 1.03.367 Foundation 4840/tcp XML External Entity\n[105052] Siemens SIMATIC Logon up to 1.5 Port 16389 Service privilege escalation\n[105003] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Sm@rtClient up to 1.0.2 TLS weak encryption\n[103347] Siemens SIMATIC CP 44x-1 RNA up to 1.4.0 Port 102 Service weak authentication\n[101086] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC up to V7.2 DCOM Interface privilege escalation\n[101085] Siemens SIMATIC PROFINET DCP Broadcast Packet privilege escalation\n[101083] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 PROFINET DCP Packet privilege escalation\n[101064] Siemens SIMATIC PROFINET DCP Broadcast Packet privilege escalation\n[95196] Siemens SIMATIC CP 343-1 3.0.44 IKEv1 weak encryption\n[94580] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC/SIMATIC PCS 7 ActiveX Component 7PK Security Features\n[94579] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 PN/SIMATIC S7-400 PN Protection Level 2 Credentials information disclosure\n[94578] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 PN/SIMATIC S7-400 PN 3.2.12 privilege escalation\n[93741] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 Web Interface cross site request forgery\n[93740] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 Session Cookie httponly information disclosure\n[93675] Siemens SIMATIC CP 1543-1 up to 2.0.27 SNMPv1/SNMPv3 privilege escalation\n[93674] Siemens SIMATIC CP 1543-1 up to 2.0.27 TIA-Portal privilege escalation\n[90226] Siemens SIMATIC NET PC-Software 13 SP1 TCP Packet privilege escalation\n[90225] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC up to 7.0 SP3/7.2 Station File information disclosure\n[90224] Siemens SIMATIC Packet privilege escalation\n[88372] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 up to 3.2.11 denial of service\n[81377] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 up to 3.x User Program Block 7PK Security Features\n[80834] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CPU up to 1.8.2 TCP Service privilege escalation\n[80833] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CPU up to 1.8.2 TCP Service privilege escalation\n[80320] Siemens SIMATIC 3.0.44 privilege escalation\n[77483] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 up to 4.1.2 cross site request forgery\n[74680] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Basic Panel Password Hash weak authentication\n[74679] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Comfort Panel privilege escalation\n[74645] Siemens SIMATIC STEP 7 12/13 7PK Security Features\n[74366] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 Cpu privilege escalation\n[73730] Siemens SIMATIC S7 1200 Cpu unknown vulnerability\n[72996] Siemens SIMATIC Tiaportal up to 13.0 information disclosure\n[72995] Siemens SIMATIC Tiaportal up to 13.0 privilege escalation\n[70652] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1518-4 Pn/dp Cpu Firmware denial of service\n[69480] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu 1200 3.0.2 privilege escalation\n[69479] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu 1200 3.0.2 cross site scripting\n[66761] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu-1211c denial of service\n[66760] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu-1211c denial of service\n[66759] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu-1211c denial of service\n[66758] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu-1211c denial of service\n[66757] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Cpu-1211c weak encryption\n[66688] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 Firmware denial of service\n[66687] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 Firmware denial of service\n[66686] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 Firmware denial of service\n[66685] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 Firmware denial of service\n[66684] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 Firmware unknown vulnerability\n[66683] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 cross site request forgery\n[66682] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 unknown vulnerability\n[66681] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 unknown vulnerability\n[66680] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 Cpu up to 1.1.1 cross site scripting\n[66343] Siemens SIMATIC Wincc Open Architecture up to 3.11 Monitoring denial of service\n[66342] Siemens SIMATIC Wincc Open Architecture up to 3.11 directory traversal\n[66341] Siemens SIMATIC Wincc Open Architecture up to 3.11 memory corruption\n[66340] Siemens SIMATIC Wincc Open Architecture up to 3.11 weak encryption\n[63838] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 7.0 directory traversal\n[63836] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 7.0 information disclosure\n[63835] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 7.0 privilege escalation\n[63834] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 7.0 memory corruption\n[63833] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 7.0 ActiveX Control memory corruption\n[63384] Siemens SIMATIC RF-MANAGER 2008 up to 3.0 memory corruption\n[62317] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 8.0 ActiveX Control information disclosure\n[62316] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 8.0 SOAP sql injection\n[62315] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 8.0 cross site scripting\n[62314] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 8.0 Configuration File privilege escalation\n[62313] Siemens SIMATIC PCS7 up to 8.0 cross site request forgery\n[61452] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 Cpu 414-3 Pn/dp 5.x Firmware memory corruption\n[61451] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 Cpu 414f-3 Pn/dp up to 6.0.2 Firmware denial of service\n[60105] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel miniweb.exe privilege escalation\n[60104] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel miniweb.exe directory traversal\n[60103] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel privilege escalation\n[60102] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel directory traversal\n[60101] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel memory corruption\n[60100] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel weak authentication\n[60099] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel memory corruption\n[60098] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel privilege escalation\n[60097] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel cross site scripting\n[60096] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel cross site scripting\n[60095] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel Administrator Account privilege escalation\n[60094] Siemens SIMATIC HMI panel weak authentication\n[58510] Siemens SIMATIC Wincc Runtime 2308 C Runtime memory corruption\n[4408] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Flexible up to 2008 Tag Simulator memory corruption\n\nMITRE CVE - https://cve.mitre.org:\n[CVE-2013-2780] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLCs 2.x and 3.x allow remote attackers to cause a denial of service (defect-mode transition and control outage) via crafted packets to UDP port 161 (aka the SNMP port).\n[CVE-2013-0700] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLCs 2.x and 3.x allow remote attackers to cause a denial of service (defect-mode transition and control outage) via crafted packets to TCP port 102 (aka the ISO-TSAP port).\n[CVE-2012-3040] Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in the web server on Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLCs 2.x through 3.0.1 allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via a crafted URI.\n[CVE-2012-3037] The Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 2.x PLC does not properly protect the private key of the SIMATIC CONTROLLER Certification Authority certificate, which allows remote attackers to spoof the S7-1200 web server by using this key to create a forged certificate.\n[CVE-2013-4912] Open redirect vulnerability in Siemens WinCC (TIA Portal) 11 and 12 before 12 SP1 allows remote attackers to redirect users to arbitrary web sites and conduct phishing attacks by leveraging improper configuration of SIMATIC HMI panels by the WinCC product.\n[CVE-2013-4911] Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) vulnerability in Siemens WinCC (TIA Portal) 11 and 12 before 12 SP1 allows remote attackers to hijack the authentication of unspecified victims by leveraging improper configuration of SIMATIC HMI panels by the WinCC product.\n[CVE-2013-3959] The Web Navigator in Siemens WinCC before 7.2 Update 1, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 8.0 SP1 and earlier and other products, exhibits different behavior for NetBIOS user names depending on whether the user account exists, which allows remote authenticated users to enumerate account names via crafted URL parameters.\n[CVE-2013-3958] The login implementation in the Web Navigator in Siemens WinCC before 7.2 Update 1, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 8.0 SP1 and earlier and other products, has a hardcoded account, which makes it easier for remote attackers to obtain access via an unspecified request.\n[CVE-2013-3957] SQL injection vulnerability in the login screen in the Web Navigator in Siemens WinCC before 7.2 Update 1, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 8.0 SP1 and earlier and other products, allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary SQL commands via unspecified vectors.\n[CVE-2013-0679] Directory traversal vulnerability in the web server in Siemens WinCC before 7.2, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 before 8.0 SP1 and other products, allows remote authenticated users to read arbitrary files via vectors involving a query for a pathname.\n[CVE-2013-0678] Siemens WinCC before 7.2, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 before 8.0 SP1 and other products, does not properly represent WebNavigator credentials in a database, which makes it easier for remote authenticated users to obtain sensitive information via a SQL query.\n[CVE-2013-0677] The web server in Siemens WinCC before 7.2, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 before 8.0 SP1 and other products, allows remote attackers to obtain sensitive information or cause a denial of service via a crafted project file.\n[CVE-2013-0676] Siemens WinCC before 7.2, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 before 8.0 SP1 and other products, does not properly assign privileges for the database containing WebNavigator credentials, which allows remote authenticated users to obtain sensitive information via a SQL query.\n[CVE-2013-0675] Buffer overflow in CCEServer (aka the central communications component) in Siemens WinCC before 7.2, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 before 8.0 SP1 and other products, allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service via a crafted packet.\n[CVE-2013-0674] Buffer overflow in the RegReader ActiveX control in Siemens WinCC before 7.2, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 before 8.0 SP1 and other products, allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a long parameter.\n[CVE-2013-0656] Buffer overflow in a third-party ActiveX component in Siemens SIMATIC RF-MANAGER 2008, and RF-MANAGER Basic 3.0 and earlier, allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted web site.\n[CVE-2012-3034] WebNavigator in Siemens WinCC 7.0 SP3 and earlier, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 and other products, allows remote attackers to discover a username and password via crafted parameters to unspecified methods in ActiveX controls.\n[CVE-2012-3032] SQL injection vulnerability in WebNavigator in Siemens WinCC 7.0 SP3 and earlier, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 and other products, allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary SQL commands via a crafted SOAP message.\n[CVE-2012-3031] Multiple cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in WebNavigator in Siemens WinCC 7.0 SP3 and earlier, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 and other products, allow remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via a (1) GET parameter, (2) POST parameter, or (3) Referer HTTP header.\n[CVE-2012-3030] WebNavigator in Siemens WinCC 7.0 SP3 and earlier, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 and other products, stores sensitive information under the web root with insufficient access control, which allows remote attackers to read a (1) log file or (2) configuration file via a direct request.\n[CVE-2012-3028] Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) vulnerability in WebNavigator in Siemens WinCC 7.0 SP3 and earlier, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 and other products, allows remote attackers to hijack the authentication of arbitrary users for requests that modify data or cause a denial of service.\n[CVE-2012-3017] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 PN CPU devices with firmware 5.x allow remote attackers to cause a denial of service (defect-mode transition and service outage) via (1) malformed HTTP traffic or (2) malformed IP packets.\n[CVE-2012-3016] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 PN CPU devices with firmware 6 before 6.0.3 allow remote attackers to cause a denial of service (defect-mode transition and service outage) via crafted ICMP packets.\n[CVE-2012-3015] Untrusted search path vulnerability in Siemens SIMATIC STEP7 before 5.5 SP1, as used in SIMATIC PCS7 7.1 SP3 and earlier and other products, allows local users to gain privileges via a Trojan horse DLL in a STEP7 project folder.\n[CVE-2011-3321] Heap-based buffer overflow in the Siemens WinCC Runtime Advanced Loader, as used in SIMATIC WinCC flexible Runtime and SIMATIC WinCC (TIA Portal) Runtime Advanced, allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (memory corruption) or possibly execute arbitrary code via a crafted packet to TCP port 2308.\n[CVE-2010-2772] Siemens Simatic WinCC and PCS 7 SCADA system uses a hard-coded password, which allows local users to access a back-end database and gain privileges, as demonstrated in the wild in July 2010 by the Stuxnet worm, a different vulnerability than CVE-2010-2568.\n\nSecurityFocus - https://www.securityfocus.com/bid/:\n[57439] SIEMENS SIMATIC S7 PLC Systems Password Disclosure Vulnerability\n[55841] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC 'web server' Component Cross Site Scripting Vulnerability\n[47993] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC Systems Replay Security Bypass and Denial of Service Vulnerabilities\n[104217] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 CPU CVE-2018-4850 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[103941] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC OA Operator IOS App CVE-2018-4847 Local Information Disclosure Vulnerability\n[103465] Siemens SIMATIC/SINUMERIK/PROFINET IO CVE-2018-4843 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[102739] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Add-On Products Multiple Security Vulnerabilities\n[101680] Siemens SIMATIC PCS 7 CVE-2017-14023 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[99582] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Sm@rtClient for Android ICSA-17-194-03 Multiple Security Vulnerabilities\n[99539] Siemens SIMATIC Logon CVE-2017-9938 Out of Bounds Write Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[99234] Siemens SIMATIC CP 44x-1 Redundant CVE-2017-6868 Authentication Bypass Vulnerability\n[96208] Siemens SIMATIC Logon CVE-2017-2684 Authentication Bypass Vulnerability\n[94436] Siemens SIMATIC CP 1543-1 Privilege Escalation and Denial of Service Vulnerabilities\n[92110] Siemens SIMATIC NET PC-Software CVE-2016-5874 Remote Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[91133] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 CPU CVE-2016-3949 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[84346] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2016-2846 Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[83110] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2016-2201 Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[83106] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2016-2200 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[78345] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC Products CVE-2015-8214 Authentication Bypass Vulnerability\n[76507] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2015- 5698 Cross Site Request Forgery Vulnerability\n[74040] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC Products CVE-2015-2823 Authentication Bypass Vulnerability\n[74028] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC Products CVE-2015-2822 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[72973] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 CVE-2015-2177 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[72695] Siemens SIMATIC STEP 7 TIA Portal Password Hash Algorithm Security Weakness\n[72691] Siemens SIMATIC STEP 7 TIA Portal Man in the Middle Information Disclosure Vulnerability\n[72627] Siemens SIMATIC STEP 7 CVE-2015-1356 Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[72625] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal Man in the Middle Information Disclosure Vulnerability\n[72624] Siemens SIMATIC STEP 7 TIA Portal CVE-2015-1355 Information Disclosure Vulnerability\n[72282] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CPU CVE-2015-1048 Open Redirection Vulnerability\n[72075] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Products CVE-2014-5233 Local Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[72073] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Products CVE-2014-5232 Local Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[72065] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Products CVE-2014-5231 Local Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[69241] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-5074 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[68880] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC and PCS7 Database Server Remote Privilege Escalation Vulnerability\n[68879] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC And PCS7 CVE-2014-4683 Remote Privilege Escalation Vulnerability\n[68876] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC And PCS7 WebNavigator Server Information Disclosure Vulnerability\n[68875] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC and PCS7 CVE-2014-4686 Privilege Escalation Vulnerability\n[68872] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC and PCS 7 CVE-2014-4685 Local Privilege Escalation Vulnerability\n[67061] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2909 HTTP Response Splitting Vulnerability\n[67059] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2908 Unspecified Cross Site Scripting Vulnerability\n[66353] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2256 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66352] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2252 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66349] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2254 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66346] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2250 Insufficient Entropy Weakness\n[66344] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2014-2258 Denial of Service Vulnerability_\n[66201] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2246 Unspecified Cross Site Scripting Vulnerability\n[66199] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2249 Cross Site Request Forgery Vulnerability\n[66198] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2257 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66196] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2255 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66195] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2251 Insufficient Entropy Vulnerability\n[66194] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2253 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66191] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2259 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[66190] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2248 Arbitrary URI Redirection Vulnerability\n[66185] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1500 CVE-2014-2247 HTTP Response Splitting Vulnerability\n[65351] SIEMENS SIMATIC WinCC Open Architecture Unspecified Arbitrary Code Execution Vulnerability\n[65349] SIEMENS SIMATIC WinCC Open Architecture Information Disclosure Vulnerability\n[65347] SIEMENS SIMATIC WinCC Open Architecture Denial of Service Vulnerabilities\n[65339] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Open Architecture Insecure Password Hash Weakness\n[61536] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal CVE-2013-4911 Cross Site Request Forgery Vulnerability\n[61535] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal CVE-2013-4912 URL Redirection Vulnerability\n[60561] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC And PCS 7 Hardcoded Credentials Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[60559] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC And PCS 7 CVE-2013-3959 Username Enumeration Weakness\n[60558] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC And PCS 7 CVE-2013-3957 SQL Injection Vulnerability\n[59399] SIEMENS SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2013-2780 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[58567] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal Multiple Security Vulnerabilities\n[58545] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC And PCS 7 Multiple Security Vulnerabilities\n[57324] Siemens SIMATIC RF Manager ActiveX Control Remote Buffer Overflow Vulnerability\n[57023] SIEMENS SIMATIC S7-1200 CVE-2013-0700 Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[55559] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 SSL Private Key Reuse Spoofing Vulnerability\n[55493] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Cross-Site Request Forgery Vulnerability\n[55492] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Multiple Security Vulnerabilities\n[54730] SIEMENS SIMATIC S7-400 Multiple Denial of Service Vulnerabilities\n[54651] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC Products DLL Loading Arbitrary Code Execution Vulnerability\n[51836] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC HMI Web Server Multiple Input Validation Vulnerabilities\n[51835] Siemens SIMATIC HMI Multiple Unspecified Cross Site Scripting Vulnerabilities\n[51177] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC Products Authentication Bypass Vulnerabilities\n[50828] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Flexible Runtime 'HmiLoad.exe' Multiple Security Vulnerabilities\n[49479] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Flexible Runtime Advanced Loader Heap Buffer Overflow Vulnerability\n[49405] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Flexible Tag Simulator Remote Memory Corruption Vulnerability\n[48988] Siemens SIMATIC Unspecified Denial of Service Vulnerability\n[48984] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 Hardcoded Credentials Security Bypass Vulnerability\n[43533] Siemens SIMATIC Manager Step7 Project Folder DLL Loading Arbitrary Code Execution Vulnerability\n[41753] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Default Password Security Bypass Vulnerability\n\nIBM X-Force - https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com:\n[78603] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC SSL weak security\n[68085] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 PLC information disclosure\n[86100] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal unspecified spoofing\n[86099] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal requests cross-site request forgery\n[83140] Siemens Simatic WinCC information disclosure\n[82942] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal HMI's web application cross-site scripting\n[82941] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal HMI cross-site scripting\n[82940] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal HTTP header injection\n[82939] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal URL information disclosure\n[82938] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal HMI cross-site scripting\n[82937] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal denial of service\n[82936] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC TIA Portal HMI security bypass\n[82911] Siemens Simatic WinCC project file denial of service\n[82908] Siemens Simatic WinCC central communications denial of service\n[82907] Siemens Simatic WinCC database permissions information disclosure\n[82906] Siemens Simatic WinCC RegReader ActiveX control buffer overflow\n[82905] Siemens Simatic WinCC Web server directory traversal\n[82904] Siemens Simatic WinCC user credentials info disclosure\n[81700] Siemens SIMATIC S7 Programmable Logic Controllers information disclosure\n[81209] Siemens SIMATIC RF Manager ActiveX control buffer overflow\n[80763] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 ISO-TAP denial of service\n[80762] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 SNMP denial of service\n[79119] Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200 unspecified cross-site scripting\n[78407] Siemens Simatic WinCC cross-site request forgery\n[78406] Siemens Simatic WinCC ActiveX control information disclosure\n[78405] Siemens Simatic WinCC SOAP SQL injection\n[78404] Siemens Simatic WinCC WebNavigator cross-site scripting\n[78403] Siemens Simatic WinCC directory traversal\n[77282] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 packet denial of service\n[77281] Siemens SIMATIC S7-400 ICMP denial of service\n[77159] Siemens SIMATIC STEP 7 and PCS 7 DLL code execution\n[72990] Siemens Simatic WinCC runtime loader denial of service\n[72989] Siemens Simatic WinCC runtime loader directory traversal\n[72988] Siemens Simatic WinCC HmiLoad buffer overflow\n[72987] Siemens Simatic WinCC TELNET daemon unauthorized access\n[72986] Siemens Simatic WinCC HMI web server and runtime loader code execution\n[72985] Siemens Simatic WinCC HMI header injection\n[72984] Siemens Simatic WinCC\n[72983] Siemens Simatic WinCC HMI server cross-site scripting\n[71952] Siemens Simatic WinCC token security bypass\n[71951] Siemens Simatic WinCC default password\n[71453] Siemens Simatic WinCC miniweb.exe denial of service\n[71452] Siemens Simatic WinCC miniweb.exe directory traversal\n[71451] Siemens Simatic WinCC HmiLoad.exe denial of service\n[71450] Siemens Simatic WinCC HmiLoad.exe directory traversal\n[71449] Siemens Simatic WinCC HmiLoad.exe buffer overflow\n[69803] Siemens Simatic WinCC runtime loader buffer overflow\n[69529] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Flexible Tag Simulator code execution\n[69006] Siemens SIMATIC S7-300 default password\n[68518] Siemens PLC Systems denial of service\n[67661] Siemens PLC Systems security bypass\n[63858] Siemens SIMATIC Manager Step7 Project Folder dynamic-linked library (DLL) code execution\n[60587] Siemens Simatic WinCC default password\n\nExploit-DB - https://www.exploit-db.com:\n[19832] Siemens Simatic S7-300 PLC Remote Memory Viewer\n[19833] Siemens Simatic S7-1200 CPU START/STOP Module\n[19831] Siemens Simatic S7-300/400 CPU START/STOP Module\n[18166] Siemens SIMATIC WinCC Flexible (Runtime) Multiple Vulnerabilities\n\nOpenVAS (Nessus) - http://www.openvas.org:\n[103372] Multiple Siemens SIMATIC Products Authentication Bypass Vulnerabilities\n[803037] Optima PLC APIFTP Server Denial of Service Vulnerabilities\n\nSecurityTracker - https://www.securitytracker.com:\n[14251] Siemens 3568i WAP Mobile Phone Malformed SMS Message DoS\n[5703] Siemens S55 SMS Send Prompt Bypass Weakness\n[1576] Siemens HiNet LP5100 IP-phone Overflow DoS\n\n"}}}
 all_keys = country.keys()
 all_keys = list(all_keys)
 val = []
 for i in all_keys:
 val.append(int(i))
 print(val)
```

In this way , i can get the right answer 443,and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the `.key()` method don't exist on dict object.
What you are looking for is the `.keys()` method.

Comment: haha what a mistake